# How to update git and github with local file structure changes?

Tags: git, github

So I've been working on some coding exercises in PyCharm for Python. They have been stored in the default PyCharm projects folder like so:

C:Users\Me\PycharmProjects\Code Project Name\

I have already used `git init` and have been pushing changes to github successfully.

Now, I've decided to start the same exercises in Java on my NetBeans IDE. Netbeans also has a default projects folder.

C:\Users\Me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Code Project Name\

I have not used `git init` on this one yet.

I have created a single folder for this project, with two sub-folders for each language:

1. User\Documents\Code Project Name\Java
2. User\Documents\Code Project Name\Python

What i'd like to do is drag and drop all of my files into this new structure. However, I'm not terribly fluent in git/github or command line operations yet, and I'm afraid a simple drag and drop will screw up my current git and github set-up. What is the correct course of action here?

Answer (score 0):

What i understood form your question is that you have 2 folders in your local device and you want the same structure in your in git hub also. The basic difference between git and github is that hub refers to cloud on which it will get stored. Just follow these commands assuming you have already done git init just move to the root of the git repository run

```sh
$ git add .       #(the . represents all)
$ git commit -m"WHATEVER COMMENT YOU WANT" 
$ git push origin --branch name
```

Comment: That's not quite what I meant. I re-wrote the question, hopefully it is more clear now.